# How to suppress display of expired entries in Solspace month calendar?

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm trying to suppress display of expired events (events that occurred in the past) on the Solspace month calendar. I'm using the out-of-the-box templates included with Solspace Calendar for Craft. Initially, I thought that there would be a start and end range for the calendar.month function:

```
{% set month = craft.calendar.month({
    date: targetDate,
    calendar: calendarHandle,
}) %}
```

But looking at the documentation, there are no parameters to pass. (https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendar.month/)

So, I looked at what is happening, and it seems that the start and end should be set on the event object (https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/event/)

In the month template, the event object is called here:

```
{% for event in day.events %}
    {% include "cal/layouts/_event.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is what is returned:

```
{% set classes = "" %}
{% set classes = classes ~ (event.allDay ? " all_day") %}

{% if event.multiDay %}
    {% set classes = classes ~ " multi_day" %}
    {% set classes = classes ~ (day.containsDate(event.startDate) ? " first_day") %}
    {% set classes = classes ~ (day.containsDate(event.endDate) ? " last_day") %}
{% endif %}

{% set style = "" %}
    {% if event.multiDay or event.allDay %}
        {% set style %}
    style="background-color: {{ event.calendar.lighterColor }} !important;
        border-color: {{ event.calendar.color }} !important;"
    {% endset %}
{% endif %}

{% if event.startDate.format('U') > now|date('U') %}

<div class="event tips{{ classes }}"{{ style }} data-toggle="popover">
        {% if event.multiDay %}
            <a href="{{ siteUrl }}cal/event/{{ event.id }}/{{ event.repeating ? event.startDate.format('Y/m/d') }}"
    style="color: {{ event.calendar.contrastColor }} !important;">
                {% autoescape false %}
                    {{ day.containsDate(event.startDate) or day.containsDate(event.endDate) ? event.title : "&nbsp;"|raw }}
                {% endautoescape %}
            </a>
        {% else %}
            {% if not event.allDay %}
                <span class="calendar-color" style="background-color: {{ event.calendar.color }};"></span>
            {% endif %}
                <a href="{{ siteUrl }}cal/event/{{ event.id }}/{{ event.repeating ? event.startDate.format('Y/m/d') }}"
                {% if event.allDay %}style="color: {{ event.calendar.contrastColor }};"{% endif %}>
                    {{ event.title }}
                </a>
        {% endif %}

    {% include "cal/layouts/_event_popover.html" %}
</div>

{% endif %}
```

I assume this is where I would set a date range, but I'm not really clear where I would set it?

UPDATE: I managed to get this working by wrapping the event output in a conditional:

```
{% if event.startDate.format('U') > now|date('U') %}
```

I added this to the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the event output in a conditional that compares the event startdate to now. I've updated the question to reflect this.